# Give an approximation for P[Y > 110]

Tags: statistical-inference

I found the following exercise interesting while reading L. Bain's book on introduction to probability and statistics:

**Let $X_1, X_2, . . . , X_{100}$ be a random sample from an exponential distribution, $X_i ∼ EXP(1)$, and
let $Y = X_1 + X_2 + · · · + X_{100}$.**

**(a) Give an approximation for P[Y > 110].**

**(b) If $\overline{X}$ is the sample mean, then approximate $P[1.1 < \overline{X} < 1.2]$.**

I know that an exponential variable of parameter $ \alpha $ has the following density function:

\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\alpha^{-1}e^{-x/\alpha}  &, \text{ si } x \geq 0. \\
0 &, \text{ si } x < 0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Also, if the sum of $ n $ exponentials of parameter $ \alpha $ is considered, it is a gamma distribution of parameters $ (n, 1 / \alpha) $. The formula for this density is:

\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\alpha^{-n}e^{-x/\alpha}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}  &, \text{ si } x \geq 0. \\
0 &, \text{ si } x < 0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

However, I have not found a way to solve this problem by estimating the result based on the above concepts. How can I do this?
Perhaps other previous concepts are necessary, or is density functions sufficient? I need some help to do this.

Comment: Probably the expectation is that you would use the central limit theorem, which would say that $Y$ is approximately normally distributed with mean $100$ and variance $100$.